# How do i find index of my object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is dynamicaly created something like this:

```
userData = Object Object Object...etc;
Object= username : ....
        level: 
        regdate:
```

JavaScript code:

```
var buildTable = function () {
for (var i = 0, l = userData.length; i < l; i++) {
    buildRow(userData[i]);
}

var buildRow = function (data) {
    var html = '<tr><td>' + data.username + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data.level + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data.regstatus + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + data.regdate + '</td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<button  value = "edit" id = "edit" onclick="tableOfUsers.editUser()">Edit</button>' +
        '<button value= "delete" id = "delete" onclick="tableOfUsers.deleteUser()">Delete</button>' + '</td>';
    $('#tableBody').append(html);
};
```

I have **edtiUser/deleteUser** function and i want when i click on **edit/delete** to **edit/delete**  my row , my question is how do i find index of my object that i want to **edite/delete** without haveing an id field just with **index of my objects**?

Comment: alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) ); use like this it will give you index

Comment: Why not just adding an index parameter to buildRow() (i.e. `var buildRow = function (data, index)`)?

Comment: Don't use `id` attributes here at all. You're calling `buildRow()` in a loop, which will create that HTML string multiple times, which means that you will have multiple elements on the same page with the same ID. This is invalid HTML. Use a class instead.

Comment: Is the Array of objects going to have an object removed when a row is deleted?

Comment: Yes when i delete i will delete something like arr.splice(index,1);

Comment: Travesty3 i know that thas somehow i want to take index of object and use it without having an id or something else..:-?

Comment: In that case the answer you accepted won't work properly because it hard-codes the index, which means that once you remove a row, all the rows ahead of it will make their index  off by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code like this

```
for (var i = 0, l = userData.length; i < l; i++) {
    buildRow(userData[i], i);
}
```

and

```
var buildRow = function (data, index) {
```

and

```
    '<button  value = "edit" id = "edit" onclick="tableOfUsers.editUser('+index+')">Edit</button>' +
    '<button value= "delete" id = "delete" onclick="tableOfUsers.deleteUser('+index+')">Delete</button>' + '</td>';
$('#tableBody').append(html);
```

notice that we are passing index to the method being called from inside html strings.

Comment: You missed the single quotes around both `+index+`s.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield, oops you commented before i edited :)

Comment: Thanks its okey now my problem is that when i create new user i have somehow to add index to it beacuse otherwise is undefined...

Comment: Now, you have to change the approach that you are following right now. you have to call same `buildRow` function after each add/edit/delete otherwise indexes will mess up everything.

Comment: Also, if you want to add another user, then there are two approaches. One you can push user to the array and then push one more row to the table and the index will always be the length of array. But, this solution has its own problem when we delete an element from array. So, IMO, you should add/edit/delete from array and call `buildRow` after each operation. If your table has less 1k rows at one time till that level it should work fine. If not, then you have to go for first logic with other modifications. Let us know your requirement in terms of performance and DOM size

Comment: I decided to cut of the "index" and i will do something like whenever you click  edit on any row i`ll take index of that row and modify / delete.